# Терминология в Классах Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Я запутался в формулировках в классах Python, может у кого то есть картинка объясняющая разницу?

**В классах в Python есть:**

Переменные - которые называются атрибутами или же свойствами класса.
Функции - которые называются методами.
Экземпляры (они же обьекты) - это что? Тоже переменные?
Поля класса - это свойство, или же просто атрибут. Поле класса так же является переменной?
Члены класса - атрибут. Тоже переменная?

Мешанина этих слов создает кашу в голове и непонимание. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Картинки, к сожалению, нет. К тому же, сдаётся мне, что, прочитав раздел ООП в какой-нибудь книжке по Python, Вы с этим разберётесь, но всё же оставлю здесь своё субъективное понимание представленных терминов.

1. Начать лучше, думаю, с объектов (экземпляров). Поясню на примере. Класс – это тип. Пусть у нас есть класс "Компьютер". Тогда объектами этого класса будут "мой компьютер", "Ваш компьютер", "Вон тот комп, что мне понравился в магазине". То есть, некоторые конкретные представители данного класса. Или же есть класс "Человек". Объектами будут Вася, Петя, Коля и т.д. Если перейти к Python:

```python
# Тот же класс человека (пока без реализации)
class Human: # Это класс
    ...

Vanya = Human() # Vanya – объект класса.
```

2. Атрибуты, свойства, поля класса – это плюс/минус одно и то же
   (Возможно кто-то пояснит тонкие различия, но, это всё-таки моё
   видение, а я вижу их как одно и то же, по крайней мере если брать
   среднее для всех языков. В некоторых Свойство – это нечто
   отдельное). Это переменная, существующая внутри объекта этого класса
   и содержащая в себе значение, отражающее некоторое свойство этого
   объекта. Если вернуться к нашему примеру, атрибуты класса "Человек" это, например, возраст, рост, пол, фамилия и т.д. Если к коду:

```python
class Human:
    def __init__(self, age, gender, height):
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.height = height

Vanya = Human(20, 'male', 180) # Это Ваня, ему 20, он мужчина, рост 180
Yulya = Human(17, 'female', 160) # Это Юля, ей 17, она девушка, рост 160

print(Vanya.age) # Сколько лет Ване? Выведет 20
print(Yulya.height) # Какого роста Юля? Выведет 160
```

(в Python, в отличие от C++, например, атрибуты обычно не объявляются заранее (хотя я не эксперт в Python, могу ошибаться), а просто вводятся как переменные с `self.` в конструкторе или другом методе).

3. Ну и про методы: методы (функции-члены) класса – это функции,
   описывающие, что умеют делать объекты класса. Чтобы сильно не
   растекаться мыслию, добавлю в пример только один метод – взрослеть.
   На нужное кол-во лет. Собственно, к коду:

```python
class Human:
    def __init__(self, age, gender, height):
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.height = height
   
    def grow_up(self, extra_age):
        self.age += extra age # Сюда бы проверку на положительность возраста, но мне лень

Vanya = Human(20, 'male', 180) # Это Ваня, ему 20, он мужчина, рост 180
Yulya = Human(17, 'female', 160) # Это Юля, ей 17, она девушка, рост 160

Vanya.grow_up(1) # Ваня повзрослел на год
Yulya.grow_up(2) # Юля повзрослела на 2 (она на севере, в космосе или где там ещё год за два)

print(Vanya.age) # Сколько лет Ване? Уже 21. Выведет 21
```

P.S. Во-первых, надеюсь не обидел носителей имён, представленных в качестве примера. Если вдруг, извините, я не хотел :) Во-вторых, надеюсь, понятно объяснил. Повторюсь, что это моё субъективное мнение, не претендующее на абсолютную истину. Исправления и уточнения приветствуются в комментариях.

P.P.S. И да, найдите что-нибудь хорошее про ООП из литературы. Не знаю насчёт Python, но Фленов в своей "Библии С#" достаточно понятно и забавно описал все принципы и термины, которые Вас интересуют. В любом случае, квалифицированный автор книги расскажет подробнее и понятнее.

Answer (score 4):

```py
class Students:
    """
    Переменная класса, которая привязана не к отдельному экземпляру, а ко всему классу
    """
    students_count = 0

    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        """
        Конструктор класса с 2 параметрами name, surname, с помощью конструктора создаётся экземпляр класса
        :param name: имя
        :param surname: фамилия
        """
        self.name = name # поле (переменная) класса
        self.surname = surname # поле класса

        Students.students_count += 1

    def display_students_count(self):
        """
        Метод для вывода кол-во студентов
        """
        print('Всего студентов: ', Students.students_count)

    def display_student(self):
        """
        Вывод текущего студента
        """
        print('Имя: {} Фамилия: {}'.format(self.name, self.surname))

"""
Экземпляр класса (Объект) - отдельны представитель класса.
Соответственно student1 = Students("Василий","Пупкин"), будет являться экземпляром класса Students
"""

student1 = Students("Василий", "Пупкин")

"""
Доступ к атрибутам класса осуществляется через .
"""

student1.display_student() # Вывод информации о текущем студенте (экземпляре класса)
student1.display_students_count() # Вывод информации об общем кол-во студентов
```

Ознакомьтесь

https://all-python.ru/osnovy/klassy.html

Answer (score 3):

Ответ выше от @Denis довольно показательный. Добавлю только некоторые уточнения.
Дело в том, что в разных коммьюнити (разных ЯП) - имеются синонимы фактически. Поэтому возникает иногда путаница, но опытный программист всегда поймет о чем речь.

А теперь поточнее:

1. Полем класса называется переменная, связанная с классом или объектом.
   Синонимы - атрибут класса, переменная член-класса.
2. Свойство — это способ доступа к внутреннему состоянию объекта, **имитирующий** поле.
   Обращение к свойству объекта выглядит так же, как и обращение к полю, но реализовано
   через вызов функции.
3. В ООП, у класса есть атрибуты - это то же самое, что и переменные, только внутри
   класса. А также есть методы - это то же самое, что и функции, только внутри класса.

Постарался изложить кратко. В интернетах полно информации об этом.